# Why is an object not moved if += is in the return statement

Tags: c++, move

I imitated `std::vector::operator+()` from Visual Studio. It looks similar to this:

```
A operator+(const int diff) const {
    A temp = *this;
    return temp += diff;
}
```

Though I have a move constructor, it uses the copy constructor, but when I use this:

```
A operator+(const int diff) const {
    A temp = *this;
    temp += diff;
    return temp;
}
```

It does actually move. Why is this?

Comment: STL templates badly need the Release build to be efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The article below explains it, but in short:

- 1. example: returns a reference and the compiler can't be convinced the value isn't used elsewhere.
- 2. example: returns a locally created value and is safe to move.

You can also fix it by returning `std::move(temp += diff)`, but this is often not preferred as it prevents the compiler from using **Return Value Optimization (RVO)**.

[https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/move-gotchas.html](https://web.mst.edu/%7Enmjxv3/articles/move-gotchas.html)

Why Visual Studio doesn't take this in account, I don't know.